# Zips are encoded differently

Tags: filesystems, zip

Apologies for the title; I'm on a Mac and I'm trying to encode a zip file so that the file system will be like that of a Windows machine. Is this possible? If so, how?

For example:

I'm currently using 7z on Windows and on Mac to zip up the same files into the same archive. I then use, for example, WinMerge to compare the zips and it's clear that they're both different yet they're encoded with the same (ported) program but on different systems.

Here's a screenshot: [WinMerge of the two zips http://f.cl.ly/items/2B2t2E2X1f2L3q082m3B/Untitled.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/2B2t2E2X1f2L3q082m3B/Untitled.png)

And here are two zips, one encoded on Windows: http://cl.ly/1O06420e0H1M and here's the OSX one: http://cl.ly/2H0X2P2i0f3P

Answer (score 0):

There is no file system in zip files (or to put it another way, zip files have their own, portable, zip filesystem).

There could be character encoding issues if you use non-ASCII file names, but that's another story.

Comment: `7z` and `zip` are different formats (though the tool `7z` is able to work with both). All those formats are intended to be portable. `7z` is also more modern, it uses unicode file names, so the problems with character encoding should be impossible. If you have a counterexample, edit your question to describe it: how do you create a problematic archive, how do you try to open it, how it fails. What platforms, what command line you use, etc.

Comment: You're right, I've added a bit more detail and a comparison between the file encoded on Windows and OSX.

Comment: Are there any *user-visible* differences, like listing or unpacking giving different results on any of your OSes? (I wouldn't have to ask if you provided a link to archives)

Comment: I've added sample zips, they're not the same as the ones in the WinMerge example as that code is slightly confidential but they'll do.